# Are questions about API-specific stuff on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Just received an interesting comment to my [question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/170/using-extensions-in-android-opengl-es-2-0).

"Are we considering very specific programming questions like these? This is a very API-specific programming question and doesn't even involve anything related to rendering techniques or usage of an API to implement them."

What do you think about it? There's no "Android API", "Android graphics" etc. on stackexchange, so is the question acceptable?

Answer (score 6):

## Yes, specific (graphics) programming questions are on topic...

...and I've actually really been missing them so far. This is site about computer graphics programming, and any problems that you encounter in this context should be on topic. Of course, if your question is not specific to graphics programming (e.g. because you encounter a syntax quirk of your language while writing a renderer), then that should rather go on Stack Overflow. But your question is specifically about a graphics API so that should certainly go here.

I would even expect specific programming questions to account for the majority of questions later on. I suspect that the reason we've mostly seen conceptual questions so far is that programming questions are harder to "make up" if you don't encounter them right then and there.

Comment: So, I can post my Qt OpenGL woes here? :P